# Codeigniter Joining Tables - Passing Parameters

Tags: sql, codeigniter, join

I'm attempting to join two tables while using codeigniter. I've done this same SQL query writing regular SQL. When I attempt to do the same in codeigniter, I keep getting errors. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. What do you guys think I'm doing wrong?

My function in model_data.php

```
function getJoinInformation($year,$make,$model)
{
 //$this->db->distinct();
 // here is where I need to conduct averages but lets just work on extracting info. 
 // from the database and join tables.
 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('tbl_car_description');
 $this->db->join('tbl_car_description', 'd.id = p.cardescription_id');
 $this->db->where('d.year', $year);
 $this->db->where('d.make', $make);
 $this->db->where('d.model', $model);
 $result = $this->db->get();
 /*
 $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_car_description',
  array(
    'year' => $year,
    'make' => $make,
    'model' => $model
   )
  );

  if($query->num_rows()) return $query->result();
  return null;
 */
}
```

My error message

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1066

Not unique table/alias: 'tbl_car_description'

SELECT * FROM (`tbl_car_description`) JOIN `tbl_car_description` ON `d`.`id` = `p`.`cardescription_id` WHERE `d`.`year` = '2006' AND `d`.`make` = 'Subaru' AND `d`.`model` = 'Baja'

Filename: C:\wamp\www\_states\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Here is the code written in SQL and it's working great. I want to do the something in codeigniter but I'm confused as to how. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks everyone.

```
$sql_2 = mysql_query("SELECT ROUND(AVG(p.value),1) AS AvgPrice, ROUND(AVG(p.mileage),1) AS AvgMileage
FROM  tbl_car_description d, tbl_car_prices p
WHERE (d.id = p.cardescription_id)
AND (d.year = '".$year."')
AND (d.make = '".$make."')
AND (d.model = '".$model."')
AND (p.approve = '1')");
```

Comment: Why do you have `join` in the CI version? Actually, why *don't* you have it in the other one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CI query references the same table twice, which I assume is a typo. However, you only need include your table alias with the table name in your Active Record call:

```
 //$this->db->distinct();
 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('tbl_car_description d');
 $this->db->join('tbl_car_prices p', 'd.id = p.cardescription_id');
 $this->db->where('d.year', $year);
 $this->db->where('d.make', $make);
 $this->db->where('d.model', $model);
 $result = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple issues: You need to include your table aliases and your join should have the name of the second table ...

```
$this->db->from('tbl_car_description AS d');
$this->db->join('tbl_car_prices AS p', 'd.id = p.cardescription_id');
```